# Replace placeholder in custom block with preprocess hook

Tags: 8, hooks

This is the first time I'm using the preprocees hook, apologies in advance.

I added a **placeholder**, `{{user-uid}}`, in a custom block body field, `<a href="advisor/{{user-uid}}">Advisor Page</a></h5>`.

My code is very simple, I have this hook theme.

```
    function boostrap_kampuster_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
        if (isset($variables['content']['#block_content'])) {
            $content = $variables['content']['#block_content'];
            
            /** custom block ID is 4 **/
            if( method_exists($content,'id') && $content->id() == '4') {
    
                $body = $variables['content']['body'][0]['#text'];
                
                $vars['user'] = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id());
                $body=str_replace('{{user-uid}}',$vars['user'],$body);
            }
        }
    }
```

I am not getting any errors but the function is not doing what it is supposed to do and replace `{{user-uid}}` with logged in user's ID either.

FYI, I cleared caches several times.

Comment: Before going the custom route, try the [Token Filter module](https://www.drupal.org/project/token_filter), it should work out of the box for common tokens like `[current-user:id]` and is more in line with the Drupal way of doing things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recommend using [@4k4's answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/300204/48114) instead.

There are a few issues here:

1. You're setting your `$body` variable, but not setting the change in your `$variables` array. You can fix this by using a [reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php), update with `$body = &$variables['content']['body'][0]['#text'];`
2. You're replacing with the user object rather than the user id. You can't insert an object into the middle of a string. You can get the id of the current users with just `\Drupal::currentUser()->id()`.
3. I'd recommend not setting the current user to `$vars['user']` in a preprocess function when you're using `$variables` as the accepted parameter. It's pretty common to use `$vars` as a shorthand in a preprocess `$variables` function and randomly setting `$vars['user']` here is definitely going to cause confusion for anyone reading this in the future.
4. I'd also recommend not using `{{ VARIABLE }}` as a custom placeholder since D8 templates use twig and that is twig syntax. For the same reasons you wouldn't use `<?php echo $VARIABLE; ?>` as your custom placeholder.

Your code updated:

```
function boostrap_kampuster_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
  if (isset($variables['content']['#block_content'])) {
    $content = $variables['content']['#block_content'];
        
    /** custom block ID is 4 **/
    if( method_exists($content,'id') && $content->id() == '4') {
      // These lines updated.
      $body = &$variables['content']['body'][0]['#text'];
      $body = str_replace('{{user-uid}}', \Drupal::currentUser()->id(), $body);
      // As 4k4 pointed out - you must set a cache context or this won't work as expected.
      $variables['#cache']['contexts'][] = 'user';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much! What if I changed, `{{user-uid}}` to `user-id`. Would `str_replace` capture and change it?

Comment: Yes. Note that you'll need to at least add the cache context as 4k4 mentioned, e.g. `$variables['#cache']['contexts'][] = 'user';`. If it were me, though, I'd look to use the lazy builder approach in [4k4's answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/300204/48114).

Answer (score 4):

In addition to @sonfd answer you also need to consider caching. The easiest way would be to add a cache context:

```
$variables['#cache']['contexts'][] = 'user';
```

But then the database needs to store a cached version for each user.

Better for performance would be to postpone replacing the placeholder by attaching a lazy builder to the render array:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
  $variables['#attached']['placeholders']['{{user-uid}}'] = [
    '#lazy_builder' => ['_mytheme_replace_uid', []],
  ];
}
```

which then returns the markup of the user UID:

```
function _mytheme_replace_uid() {
  return [
    '#markup' => \Drupal::currentUser()->id(),
    '#cache' => ['contexts' => ['user']],
  ];
}
```

**Drupal 9**

Drupal 9 requires using only trusted callbacks. So define a class implementing [TrustedCallbackInterface](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Security%21TrustedCallbackInterface.php/interface/TrustedCallbackInterface/9.1.x) or [RenderCallbackInterface](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element%21RenderCallbackInterface.php/interface/RenderCallbackInterface/9.1.x):

*mytheme/src/MythemeLazyBuilders.php:*

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\mytheme;

use Drupal\Core\Render\Element\RenderCallbackInterface;

class MythemeLazyBuilders implements RenderCallbackInterface {

  public static function replaceUid() {
    return [
      '#markup' => \Drupal::currentUser()->id(),
      '#cache' => ['contexts' => ['user']],
    ];
  }

}
```

and add it to the render array:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
  $variables['#attached']['placeholders']['{{user-uid}}'] = [
    '#lazy_builder' => ['\Drupal\mytheme\MythemeLazyBuilders::replaceUid', []],
  ];
}
```