# Token Replacement via Lazy_builder

Tags: hooks, caching, tokens, sessions

I've spent the best part of the last day or two trying to implement lazy_builder (as seen in this brilliant tutorial https://github.com/joachim-n/drupalcon-europe-2020-lazy-builders).

However, rather than with a block or page render. I'd like to implement the lazy_builder into hook_tokens() and make the $replacements value dynamic so that it uses the lazy_builder.

We have a value saved to session that we use as the value of a token (so it back be used across the site).

```
$session = \Drupal::request()->getSession();
$session->get('my_value');
```

I've tried setting $bubbleable_metadata with both addCacheContexts and addCacheableDependency

```
$bubbleable_metadata->addCacheContexts(['session']);
```

&

```
$session = \Drupal::request()->getSession();
$bubbleable_metadata->addCacheableDependency($session);
```

However both these options make the page UNCACHABLE.

I'd like to keep the page a cache HIT, but load in the token value via lazy_builder.

My question is, is there anyway to leverage lazy_builder, in the token replacement?

```
/**
 * Implements hook_tokens().
 */
function mymodule_tokens($type, $tokens, array $data, array $options, BubbleableMetadata $bubbleable_metadata) {
  $replacements = array();
  if ($type == 'my_token') {
    foreach ($tokens as $name => $original) {
      // Find the desired token by name
      switch ($name) {
        case 'my_token':
          $session = \Drupal::request()->getSession();
          //make the below use lazy_builder
          $replacements[$original] = $session->get('tracking');
          break;
      }
    }
  }
  // Return the replacements.
  return $replacements;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! `#lazy_builder` is used in render arrays. It's not clear how you would use it to change the value returned from a token.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So any suggestions on how to use this token, but still make the page a CACHE HIT?

Comment: Which page? `hook_tokens()` could be invoked for every page. The code shown in the question doesn't make clear for which page it would be used or called.

Comment: Any page where this token could be placed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/300204/47547) might be helpful. In your case you could try to bubble up the attachment from the token itself:

```
$replacements[$original] = '<my-placeholder>';

$bubbleable_metadata->addAttachments([
  'placeholders' => [
    '<my-placeholder>' => [
      '#lazy_builder' => ['\Drupal\mytheme\MythemeLazyBuilders::replaceUid', []],
    ],
  ],
]);
```

You not really need the Drupal token system, you can attach placeholders almost everywhere in the rendering process, but for some cases this could be a convenient way to make a lazy builder available.

Comment: This is really promising @4k4 and I got the attachment pulling in LazyBuilder render class. However I am getting the below error.

TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Drupal\\Core\\Cache\\CacheableMetadata::createFromRenderArray() must be of the type array, string given, called in /var/www/html/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php on line 358 in /var/www/html/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Cache/CacheableMetadata.php on line 149

What would the render class need to return? Should I still be setting a replacement value on the token, or will the attachment take care of it. Thanks

Comment: This is what I meant, you have two token/placeholder mechanism chained, which is normally not necessary. In the first token replacement you could replace the Drupal token with a non-visible HTML tag placeholder `<my-placeholder>`.

Comment: In the second replacement the lazy builder has to return a render array, this means at least a '#markup' element like in the linked answer.