# What is the new methodology for Form Pre-Render in order to utilize TrustedCallbackInterface

Tags: theming, forms

We are upgrading our sites one at a time from Drupal 8 to Drupal 9 and there is one line of code in our custom theme that is the last of our problems.

We get the following error on View that uses an exposed filter:

```
Drupal\Core\Security\UntrustedCallbackException: Render #pre_render callbacks must be methods of a class that implements \Drupal\Core\Security\TrustedCallbackInterface or be an anonymous function. The callback was MYSITE_form_alter_views_exposed_form_MYVIEW_pre_render. See https://www.drupal.org/node/2966725 in Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doTrustedCallback() (line 96 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Security/DoTrustedCallbackTrait.php).
```

In the OURTHEME.theme file, we have this function:

```
/**
 * Custom form alter for events.
 */
function OURTHEME_form_alter_views_exposed_form_events_pre_render($form) {
  $fields = [
    'field_start_date_value',
    'field_end_date_value',
    'field_address_locality',
  ];
  foreach ($fields as $field) {
    $form[$field]['#title_display'] = 'after';
  }
  $form['field_date_range_end_value']['#prefix'] = '<div class="event-exposed-form">';
  $form['field_event_address_locality']['#suffix'] = '</div>';
  return $form;
}
```

And the function is called here (just a snippet of the code in this function):

```
/**
 * These are the alterations to forms variables before they are rendered.
 */
function OURTHEME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'views_exposed_form' && strpos($form['#id'], 'views-exposed-form-events-') === 0) {
    $form['#pre_render'][] = 'OURTHEME_form_alter_views_exposed_form_events_pre_render';
  }
  return $form;
}
```

From what I could divine from the research I've done so far, it seems that normally whatever class these kinds of functions are utilized in have implemented Drupal's `TrustedCallbackInterface`. Unfortunately, the only information I have found has been throughout the various patches being applied to projects throughout Drupal.org, so I'm trying to cobble together a methodology from random applications of it.

Of course, there's the Drupal API page, but that's not especially helpful when it comes to actually putting the pieces together into a useful methodology without knowing the rest of the API like the back of your hand.

Does anyone know if there's any documentation on how to apply the `TrustedCallbackInterface` to a function that previously used `$form['#pre_render'][]`, especially in THEME.theme which is not set up the same as any old custom class in a Module?

Comment: The error is right there - you are adding a function to pre_render that is not approved to be called. https://www.drupal.org/node/2966725

Comment: So, the answer is just "Don't try altering the form pre-render. Do what you need to do another way." ?

Comment: Look at the linked change record

Comment: The .theme file isn't a class. So I should create an src folder in my theme and move the code from my .theme file to a new class declaration?

Comment: Yes, see for example https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/300204/47547. For a different callback type, but it shows a class implementing RenderCallbackInterface in a theme.

Comment: Thanks for the more realistic example. In the end, I had such a difficult time figuring out the proper way to pass the values around for a form and its elements that I did give up and scrapped this methodology entirely  in favor of just altering the twig template instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this:

in your new module **my_prerenders** in *my_prerenders/src/* add a new class:

```
namespace Drupal\my_prerenders;

use Drupal\Core\Security\TrustedCallbackInterface;


class MyPreRenders implements TrustedCallbackInterface {

  /**
   * @inheritDoc
   */
  public static function trustedCallbacks() {
    return ['formAlterViewsExposedFormEventsPreRender'];
  }

  public function formAlterViewsExposedFormEventsPreRender($form) {
    $fields = [
    'field_start_date_value',
    'field_end_date_value',
    'field_address_locality',
    ];
    foreach ($fields as $field) {
      $form[$field]['#title_display'] = 'after';
    }
    $form['field_date_range_end_value']['#prefix'] = '<div class="event-exposed-form">';
    $form['field_event_address_locality']['#suffix'] = '</div>';
    return $form;
  }

}
```

In **OURTHEME.theme** you just have to use:

```
use Drupal\my_prerenders\MyPreRenders;

...
...

$form['#pre_render'][] = [MyPreRenders::class, 'formAlterViewsExposedFormEventsPreRender'];
```

instead of

```
$form['#pre_render'][] = 'OURTHEME_form_alter_views_exposed_form_events_pre_render';
```